# Using Spark or Razor viewengine with OpenRasta

Tags: viewengine, openrasta

has anyone used Spark or Razor view engine with OpenRasta framework?
or any suggestion on the view engine other than the build in WebForms ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Spark and Razor ViewEngine support for OpenRasta available at

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-codecs-razor

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-codecs-spark

You will probably have to build from source from these locations.